# PHP sqlsrv_query select statement not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I want to make a consult to the `MSSQLSERVER` with a `SELECT STATEMENT` but the `sqlsrv_query` is returning `FALSE` to me.

I already tested the query and its working fine, am I passing the parameters correctly?

Here is my code:

```
    if($conn === false)
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }


     try
        {
$email = "somedbemail@email.com";
            $sql = "select Usuario.Email, Usuario.Senha FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario.Email = (?)";

            $params = array($email);

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

if($stmt != False)
        {
            if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_Array($stmt))
            {
                $email_Con = $row['Email'];
                $psw_Con = $row['Senha'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "alguma coisa";
            }


        }
else
{
   echo "It always enters here!";
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `sqlsrv_errors()`?

Comment: "SQLSTATE: IMSSP<br />code: -14<br />message: An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.<br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible problems.

The first is the format of your query. You are using:

```
select Usuario.Email, Usuario.Senha FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario.Email = (?)
```

Where I think you should be doing:

```
select Usuario.Email, Usuario.Senha FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario.Email = ?
```

The second is that the `An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query()` message is common when the connection is not correct ([Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/52b77cb6-6de6-40e8-b306-59d5c4a560c1/an-invalid-parameter-was-passed-to-sqlsrvquery)). So double check that your connection is a valid resource.

Comment: Done that... didn't work and received the same error

Comment: even if I try
  $sql = "select Usuario.Email, Usuario.Senha FROM Usuario WHERE Usuario.Email = 'somedbemail@email.com'";

           // $params = array($email);

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);

I get the same error.

Comment: Its not the connection because i have 

$server = "[SERVER]";
    $user = "[USER]";
    $pwd = "PSW";
    $db = "DB";

    if($conn === false)
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
    }

Comment: I was wrong, my connection string was quite wrong. Thank you for giving me these options... I tough the error was the parameters of the QUERY, not the SQLSRV_QUERY parameters...